# print the next word after matching either one of the pattern. next word could be space separated or equal sign

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, grep

print the next word after matching either one of the pattern i.e "-l" or "--log-file=". next word could be space separated or equal sign "="

```
cat server.log
server_options='-l /tmp/server_log --log-level=1'

cat server1.log
server_options='--log-file=/tmp/server1_log --log-level=1'
```

expected output for the first example [only the very next word after finding pattern and not till end of line]:-

```
/tmp/server_log
```

expected output for the second example [only the very next word after finding pattern and not till end of line]:-

```
/tmp/server1_log
```

With the following it prints when "-l" is specifed

```
$ grep -Po '^[^#;].*(-l|--log-file) \K.*(?=.)' server.log
/tmp/server_log
```

but it doesn't work when "--log-file=" is specified

```
 $ grep -Po '^[^#;].*(-l|--log-file) \K.*(?=.)' server1.log
```

Note:- there can be multiple options for example "-a" "-f" along with -l or --log-file and can be in any position inside quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -Po "^[^#;].*(-l |--log-file=)\K[^\s']+" server.log
```

Remember that `-l` is followed by a space but `-log-file` is followed by a `=`

This `grep` requires a gnu grep.

Comment: awk will print the quote.

Comment: there can be multiple options for example "-a" "-f" along with -l or --log-file and can be in any position inside quotes and also want to ignore lines start with "#" when using awk example that you gave

Comment: on the awk example you have just posted, prints all words next to the string found. but I need only very next word i.e "/tmp/server.log"

but it prints till end of line "/tmp/server.log --log-level=1"

Comment: even grep answer is printing till end of line whereas only very next phrase is required

grep -Po "^[^#;].*(-l |--log-file=)\K[^']+" server.log

/tmp/server.log --log-level=1

Comment: please change the input file as 

server_options='--log-file=/tmp/ime-server.log --log-level=1' and try

Comment: posted the expected output for 1st and 2nd example on the question now, I just need the very next word and not till end of line after finding pattern

Comment: My **updated** `grep` command is already producing same output. Did you try?

Comment: tried now and it is working thanks much for your help !